# Selecting childs from parent CLASS to child ID using jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty sure this is just a semantics problems but I would be very grateful if someone could lead me in the right direction.

The HTML:

```
<div class="grid_7">
  <div class="big">
    The elusive
  </div>
</div>
```

The function:

```
$(function(){
$(' .grid_7 > .big').bigtext();});
```

I'm trying to grab .grid_7's child .big

Here's a link to the real code:

http://designobvio.us/dov2/index.html

I know the script works cuz when i do

```
 $(function(){
$(' .grid_7:first-child').bigtext();});
```

everything fine... therefore, it's semantics? or am I crazy?

Thank you so much

Comment: What is `bigtext()`?. Can you post the function?

Comment: hey sorry for the late response! we figured it out! I was dumb.  however bigtext is an excellent jQuery function that allows you to auto scale text to it's parent's width.  http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/  heres the link. Upvoting for your support!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation on the [`bigtext` plugin website](http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/):

> the BigText jQuery plugin takes a single element and sizes the **text
>   inside of its child `<div>`s** to fit the width of the parent element.

Your `.big` element doesn't have any child `div` elements, so nothing happens.

The reason your `:first-child` attempt works is that `:first-child` returns the first `.grid_7` element, not the first of its children.

You need to apply the `bigtext` method to `.grid_7`, or you need to add another `div` around `.big`.

Comment: I really got confused when it was so easy.  Thank you for the answer!